# find "li" after Math.random() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, random

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/d2fMz/260/)**

Hi,

I am finding the Random Number of "LI", now Iam not able find content inside of selected Random Number.,

kindly help find the inner content, not sure how to find the content by keeping random selected value.

Appreciate your help!!

Thanks

```
JS: 

$(function(){

   getRandomMaxCount = $('#flexslider-1 .flex-viewport ul.slides li').length;
   var minNumber = 1;
   var maxNumber = getRandomMaxCount;
   randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

   function randomNumberFromRange(min,max) {
        alert(Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min));
        console.log($(this).find('li'))
   }

})



HTML : 

<div id="flexslider-1" class="flexslider flexslider-processed">
   <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
      <ul class="slides" style="width: 400%; transition-duration: 0s;">
         <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>


          <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
            <div class="doctor-profile ">
               <div class="thumb-img">
                  <div class="field-content">
                     <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                        <div class="content">
                           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">  
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span></div>
               <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span></div>
               <p class="dr-description"></p>
               <div></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
      <li><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li>
      <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not referring to `this`...

Comment: @RayonDabre, ? not sure what im doing wrong here.. once i get the random value of li, i want to find inner html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `:nth-child` selector and mention the required `index`

Try this:

```js
$(function() {

  var getRandomMaxCount = $('#flexslider-1 .flex-viewport ul.slides li').length;
  var minNumber = 1;
  var maxNumber = getRandomMaxCount;
  randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

  function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    console.log($('.slides li:nth-child(' + index + ')'));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flexslider-1" class="flexslider flexslider-processed">
  <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <ul class="slides" style="width: 400%; transition-duration: 0s;">
      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315806--2" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d1png-2">d1.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d1.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/karthikeyan">Karthikeyan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75666</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="width: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
        <div class="doctor-profile ">
          <div class="thumb-img">
            <div class="field-content">
              <div id="file-315811--3" class="file file-image file-image-png">
                <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/d3png">d3.png</a></h2>
                <div class="content">
                  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://vietnam.test3.meadjohnson.net/sites/default/files/d3.png" alt="" draggable="false">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dr-name contact-name"><span class="field-content"><a href="/ashraf-jahan">Ashraf Jahan</a></span>
          </div>
          <div id="doc_id" style="display:none;"><span>75661</span>
          </div>
          <p class="dr-description"></p>
          <div></div>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/d2fMz/263/)